# Nodejs dynamically add HTML content when documents are inserted in collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, dynamic-html

When a document is added to the MongoDB Collection, I want to add a new HTML element (div,p,img,etc..) to my homepage.html . The homepage.html has to be dynamically updated by the server, by 'Detecting' the changes in the MongoDB database Collection.  I'm using Express.js to respond to client requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your task cannot be done by only using those technologies. You have to use some kind of socket programming framework like [socket.io](http://socket.io/). 
I recommend you to refer this real time chat app creating blog post to get some sort of idea of your case. [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socketio-and-expressjs--net-31708) is the link

Thanks. Hope you will understand me.